# VBA object doesn't support property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sort a group of worksheets based on several criteria, but the size of table and the column positions varies in each sheet.

This is a sorting procedure I've ran into error.

This is the line, I adopted the code from recording a macro, and changed the original range to the following, and it returns an error.

`.SetRange .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))`

object doesn't support property or method

Can someone help me with it? Thanks!

```
Sub SortAll()
    Dim RngAll As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim reportPeriod As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String


        reportPeriod = Sheets("Ranking Report").Range("C36").Value


        With Worksheets(reportPeriod)


        lastColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set aCell = .Range("B4:BT4").Find(What:="Penetration Overall", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            col = aCell.Column
            colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

            lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> This is your range
            Set RngAll = .Range(colName & "5:" & colName & lRow)

            Debug.Print RngAll.Address
        '~~> If not found
        Else
            MsgBox "Range Not Found"
        End If


        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=RngAll, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

        End With

        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(reportPeriod).Sort
            .SetRange .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
            .header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```

Comment: Probably you need to add `Worksheets(reportPeriod)` to `.Range` and `.Cells` calls in this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the column index number, you do not need to rework it into an xlA1 range address.

```
Sub SortAll()
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
    Dim reportPeriod As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long

    reportPeriod = Sheets("Ranking Report").Range("C36").Value
    With Worksheets(reportPeriod)
        lc = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Set aCell = .Rows(4).Find(What:="Penetration Overall", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            lCol = aCell.Column
            lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, lCol).End(xlUp).Row

            With .Cells(4, 1).Resize(lRow, lc)
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(lCol), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Range Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! That's a much better code than mine. Just a question, what's the difference between the lr and lRow, why did you use two variables to find the last row?

Comment: @qshngv - lr is the last non-blank cell in column B and lRow is the last non-blank cell in the column that contains *Penetration Overall* in row 4. I didn't see how lr was used but I left it in in case this was intended to fit into a larger module.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that if I define the Sort Area in advance, then reference it in the sort formula, it works.

Like this, I still don't understand why is this. If anyone could explain, I'm much appreciated!

```
Sub SortAll()
    Dim RngAll As Range
    Dim SortA As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim reportPeriod As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String


        reportPeriod = Sheets("Ranking Report").Range("C36").Value


        With Worksheets(reportPeriod)


                lastColumn = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                Set SortA = .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
                Set aCell = .Range("B4:BT4").Find(What:="Penetration Overall", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        col = aCell.Column
                        colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

                        lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                        'This is your range
                        Set RngAll = .Range(colName & "5:" & colName & lRow)

                        Debug.Print RngAll.Address
                        'If not found
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Range Not Found"
                    End If


                .Sort.SortFields.Clear
                .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=RngAll, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
                xlSortNormal

        End With

        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(reportPeriod).Sort
            .SetRange SortA
            .header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```

Comment: Your original problem was redefining the `With ... End With` but using the same `.Range` and `.Cells` within the redefinition. The periods used to prefix .Range and .Cells means that they belong to the With ... End With. When you redefined it, the references were no longer valid.